# How can I manage videos with OS X, iPhone and Sony Nex 3N?

Tags: iphone, osx

I asked this question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163818/how-can-i-get-my-videos-from-a-digital-camera-to-osx-and-iphone) but I find it is also relevant here. So let's take fresh: I have many videos in iPhone, many videos in Sony Nex 3N and I have Macbook Air laptop. My goal is to create training videos having video collages.

**How can I combine the videos from iPhone and Sony to video collages easily?**

Comment: You'll need to describe in much more detail what you're trying to do before we can give you a reasonable answer. Aside from saying, get Final Cut Pro or some other editing app and import the footage into your computer, we need to know specifics of what you want to do.

Comment: @user1118321 my Final Cut Pro used for merging Sony videos like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVJJER711bk). I want to merge iPhone vids and the Sony vids. My goal is to create sport videos like [here](http://instagram.com/p/xF7p_TQ1JU/?modal=true) and collage sport videos to which I need videos from my iPhone and from my Sony. I have applications in iPhone like ClipCatch to do Collage videos. I am able to do awesome videos with iPhone like [here](http://instagram.com/p/xGFaigvWM0) but Sony is so much better many times with its inverted screen so will merge videos over iPhone/Sony.

Comment: OK, so you want to move the Sony clips from the Sony camera into your iPhone and then use them on the iPhone with ClipCatch? And the problem you're having is easily moving them over to the iPhone? If so, are you comfortable using the command-line on OS X?

Comment: @user1118321 I love commandline! Proud Vi veteran :)

Comment: This question is both unclear what you are asking and likely an overly broad question asking "how do I do video editing?" which is an entire field of study that can't possibly be summarized in one question and answer.

Comment: Additionally, please be careful when posting very similar questions on multiple sites.  It does appear that the questions are actually slightly different in this case (one appears to be asking how to get the files off the cameras and the other is asking how to combined them?), however asking the same question on multiple sites is greatly discouraged and will normally result in one of the questions being closed outright or migrated and closed as dupe.  We want to make sure we get the best answers possible to a question and if the same exact question is listed twice, one of them will suffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're a command-line user, you can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) to do the conversion for you. I suspect when you mount your Sony camera, it probably always gets the same volume name. (Probably something like /Volumes/SONY/ or /Volumes/DSC/ or something like that.) You could write a script that basically walks through the directory containing the movies, and converts them to a suitable format, saving them on your hard drive.

Looking at iTunes in Automator.app, I see that it supports an "Import Files Into iTunes" function. You could probably make an Automator action that calls your ffmpeg script, then imports the results into iTunes. From there, you just sync your iPhone. (Not sure if it will auto-sync large videos via iCloud or not, but it might.)

I'm not the best at scripting or Automator, but you can probably get an answer to the specifics on either Ask Different or Super User.